# Testing sha256(abi.encodePacked(_argument))

Tags: testing, truffle-test, sha3, hash-algorithm

When trying to test a smart contract that uses

```
 sha256(abi.encodePacked(_myargument))
```

I don't get the same hash on truffle !
I tried both

```
web3.utils.keccak256('_myargument')
web3.utils.sha3('_myargument')
```

but both gave a hash different from what I get within the smart contract function.

So I thought it was because of abi.encodePacked, thus I tried

```
web3.utils.sha3(web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('string', _myargument))
```

but the hash is still not the one expected.

Do you know why and how to get the same hash ? I don't understand why in general people use abi.encodePacked before hashing the argument with sha256(). If abi.encodePacked is involved, is it really necessary to keep it or can I safely remove it to just use  sha256(_myargument) instead of  sha256(abi.encodePacked(_myargument))  inside the smart contract ?

Best regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to know that `sha256` and `keccak256` functions are not the same. Check the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) to see available functions.

`sha256` (with pyhton):

```
>>> sha256("Hello World!").hexdigest()
'7f83b1657ff1fc53b92dc18148a1d65dfc2d4b1fa3d677284addd200126d9069'
```

`keccak256` (with web3):

```
web3.utils.keccak256("Hello World!")
'0x3ea2f1d0abf3fc66cf29eebb70cbd4e7fe762ef8a09bcc06c8edf641230afec0'
```

To get the same hash:

```
contract Hash {
    function func() external pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Hello World!")) ;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
decoded output 
{
    "0": "bytes32: 0x3ea2f1d0abf3fc66cf29eebb70cbd4e7fe762ef8a09bcc06c8edf641230afec0"
}
```

Choose:

```
truffle(development)> web3.utils.soliditySha3("Hello World!")
'0x3ea2f1d0abf3fc66cf29eebb70cbd4e7fe762ef8a09bcc06c8edf641230afec0'
truffle(development)> web3.utils.keccak256("Hello World!")
'0x3ea2f1d0abf3fc66cf29eebb70cbd4e7fe762ef8a09bcc06c8edf641230afec0'
truffle(development)> web3.utils.sha3("Hello World!")
'0x3ea2f1d0abf3fc66cf29eebb70cbd4e7fe762ef8a09bcc06c8edf641230afec0'
```

About [`abi.encodePacked(...)`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions)

> `abi.encodePacked(...) returns (bytes memory)`: Performs [packed
>   encoding](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abi-spec.html#abi-packed-mode) of the given arguments. Note that packed encoding can be
>   ambiguous!

You can test it, but with one argument, the result hash will be the same if you don't use `abi.encodePacked(...)`.

**EDIT**:

From docs:

> If you use `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))` and both `a` and `b`
>   are dynamic types, it is easy to craft collisions in the hash value by
>   moving parts of `a` into `b` and vice-versa. More specifically,
>   `abi.encodePacked("a", "bc") == abi.encodePacked("ab", "c")`.

- `abi.encodePacked(...)` encode dynamic types without length and
  static types are not padded if they are shorter than 32 bytes.
- `abi.encode(...)` ABI-encodes the given arguments

`abi.encode("a", "bc")` result:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 // Start offset for the first parameter ("a")
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080 // Start offset for the second parameter ("bc")
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // Length of the first parameter ("a")
0x6100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // Padded to 32 bytes ("a") UTF-8 encoded
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 // Length of the second parameter ("bc")
0x6263000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // Padded to 32 bytes ("bc") UTF-8 encoded

keccak256: 0x68cd083d4c97fcbd081751d5390da5b37f5c485fd0879180d4816c456e8e532c
```

`abi.encode("ab", "c")` result:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040 // Start offset for the first parameter ("ab")
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080 // Start offset for the second parameter ("c")
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 // Length of the first parameter ("ab")
0x6162000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // Padded to 32 bytes ("ab") UTF-8 encoded
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 // Length of the second parameter ("c")
0x6300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // Padded to 32 bytes ("c") UTF-8 encoded

keccak256: 0x8c98d57214b9f76c3240d1fc677eb9fc1529ec2a4f56949bb6abe31d50b4b7c6
```

`abi.encodePacked("a", "bc")` result:

```
0x61    // ("a")  UTF-8 encoded without padding
0x6263  // ("bc") UTF-8 encoded without padding

keccak256: 0x4e03657aea45a94fc7d47ba826c8d667c0d1e6e33a64a036ec44f58fa12d6c45
```

`abi.encodePacked("ab", "c")` result:

```
0x6162  // ("ab") UTF-8 encoded without padding
0x63    // ("c")  UTF-8 encoded without padding

keccak256: 0x4e03657aea45a94fc7d47ba826c8d667c0d1e6e33a64a036ec44f58fa12d6c45
```

Comment: @KNK Ok I get it. But with this technique is it sure that I will never get same output with different inputs because of abi.encodePacked ? They say "Unless there is a compelling reason, abi.encode should be preferred to abi.encodePacked." so is abi.encode better for me if I really need to get different outputs for different inputs ? Plus note that there are places where I use hashing with several arguments inside the smart contract

Comment: @KevinWad Answer edited. Probably for your purpose its better to use `abi.encode` to avoid possible collisions.

Comment: @KNK for the last 2 example you meant abi.encodePacked("a", "bc") and abi.encode("ab", "c"), right ? So we see that with abi.encodePacked we get same output with different inputs although with encode we don't have this issue. If I use abi.encode, will the keccak256() function give the same hash when testing on truffle ? Best regards

Comment: @KevinWad Sorry, there was an error in the answer, now corrected. Yes, you can get the same hash on truffle but you need to transform the arguments to ABI-encoded format, read here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/convert-contract-arguments-from-json-to-abi-encoded-format

Comment: Am I mistaken, or did this answer not really give an answer to the original question? The first line of the answer is "sha256 is different from keccak256", and the answer then proceeds to explain keccak256. But the original question concerned itself with testing sha256 on truffle.

Answer (score 1):

abi.encodePacked is padding your argument, so sha3(0) is not the same as sha3(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) assuming that your parameter is a number or a hex string

If it is a hex string - you should use web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint256', _myargument) not web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('string', _myargument)

Also please note that sha256 and keccak256 are not the same hash function

Comment: Hi @KNK thanks for reply ! The argument type is a string but I get this error when I try what you said:   Error: invalid number value (arg="", coderType="uint256", value="BMW")

Answer (score 1):

It bears noticing that `web3.utils.keccak256` and `web3.utils.sha3` are synonyms, so no point using both. You should use `keccak256`, if given a choice, because the function it implements is not actually Sha3 as defined in the NIST standard, but rather a different function (an early implemementation of Keccak256, before it was modified for the SHA3 standard). I've written about this [here](https://coders-errand.com/hash-functions-without-mistakes-part-2/).

Because of this, Solidity removed the `sha3()` function in 0.5.0, and kept just `keccak256()`.

You can, however, invoke the 256-bit version of SHA2 in Solidity by using `sha256()`. This calls a precompiled contract instead of converting to an EVM opcode like `keccak256()` does, but I haven't compared the gas costs.

Comment: Thanks for this precision. If I want to use a hash function for mining purpose and I want the mining system to be as secure as bitcoin. Does it have an impact to use keccack256 instead of sha256 like bitcoin? If yes is it still secure enough if I use keccak256? Best regards

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean by "security"? In terms of the hash function per se, SHA2 has still not been broken. Last I read (https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Hash-Functions/NIST-Policy-on-Hash-Functions), NIST don't recommend an upgrade from SHA-2 to SHA-3.
Their comparison of security parameters (https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf, pg 23) shows both algorithms are pretty close (slight mismatch on the 2nd preimage resistance). I'd presume Keccak256 and SHA-3 to be equivalent in this comparison. Remember, sha256 is the older of the two.

Comment: @Kevin Wad, In terms of mining and security, you could look at another angle. The security of the blockchain depends a lot on the concetration of miners. So, if a hash can only be efficiently executed by specialized hardware, the community may concentrate around big mining pools, leading to a loss of decentralization and making the blockchain arguably less secure. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was talking about the risk of breaking the hash function as it already happened at least twice to Sha2 in the past 20 years. But in fact you put in light another point: does the choice of sha256 or keccak256 have an impact on asic mining and easyness to mine for regular people?